# How to make Seek bar in Slide menu?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a student making an application using an android studio for practice. I want to make seek bar in basic slide menu, which android studio provides as navigation drawer. I searched about it but couldn't find it. If the answer already exists, I apologise. Pretty hard to search by English...

Is there a way to create seek bar in slide menu so users can edit the value? For instance, users can control size or opacity of pen directly by editing the value of seek bar in slide menu. I made an example image. Thanks for reading.

[image]

Comment: not sure if you can make it using menu item. You can create a layout containing a text view and seek bar and add it in the navigation drawer menu.

Comment: Make it seek bar as normal text menuitem ,then onclick  use pop dialog   inside you make  seek bar.

Comment: @SripadRaj Thanks for comment. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `NavigationView` to accommodate `android Views` instead of `menu`.So that you can customize the entire `Navigation Drawer Menu`.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:entries="@array/sports_array"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Because it was my first question, I didn't know there are accept function. I did it!