# Add Seekbar to Navigation Menu

Tags: java, menuitem, seekbar

All I want to do is add a Seekbar to the menu drawer in my application. Apparently this is difficult.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158048/how-to-make-seek-bar-in-slide-menu) where someone appears to have answered the question. But the answer does not provide enough code, and I can't get this to work.

Anyone know another way, or know how to complete the answer listed above?